# Series solution of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

My equation reads:
[image]

I expand the solution:[image]

For example: to zeroth order differential equation reads:
[image]

[image]

where the index i+i is understood modulo 2.

At order $\Lambda^4$ equation reads:
[image]

Proposing the ansatz:
[image]

We get: [image]

At arbitrary order in $\Lambda^4$ we make the following ansatz
[image]

We also have an expansion of u
[image]

Could anyone help me with writing a code to compute $d_{l,i}^{(n)}$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For series solution of ode look at [AsymptoticDSolveValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html)

Comment: It would be helpful if 1) all quantities are defined (e.g., $a_\text{FN}$), 2) starting equations are typed in MA format, 3) important transitions are explained. Consider that we may not have expertise in your field. For instance, it is not immediately obvious why "the index i+i is understood modulo 2", in MA there are `HankelH1[n,z]` and `HankelH2[n,z]` functions.